# Triplets 4th of power of first equals to sum of other two

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I was looking through the admission test for the University Normale of Pisa and I found a problem that I don't know how to solve, it state something like that:

Find all the triplets of number (x, y, z) such that:
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}\
x^4 = y + z\\
y^4 = z + x\\
z^4 = y + x
\end{array} \right. 
$$

**EDIT**:
It ask for **real** number.

All: Please observe that the question was earlier tagged *elementary-number-theory*. This lead several posters to assume that the variables should be integers. Several answers may appear to be strange as a consequence of that./JL

Comment: Are you sure the last one isn't $x + y$ (for symmetry)?

Comment: Are $x,y,z$ real or integers? Or positive integers?

Comment: Should that last $y+y$ be $x+y$?

Comment: yes it should sorry about the typo... I am fixing it.. @vonbrand yes

Comment: @N.S. integers in general

Comment: Sorry, it is real number not integer

Comment: If the variables are real, then *elementary-number-theory* is a wrong tag. I took the liberty of changing that.

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality we can assume that $x \geq y \geq z$. Then it is clear that $x \geq 0$ (otherwise all three are negative, which is not possible)

$$x^4=y+z \le 2x \,.$$

Thus $x^3 \leq 2 \Rightarrow x=0 \, \mbox{or} \, x=1 \,.$

If $x=0$ we have $y,z \leq 0$ and  $y=z^4 \geq 0 \Rightarrow y=0$ and $z=0$.

If $x=1$, then $z \leq y \leq 1$ and $y+z=1$. This implies that $z=0$ and $y=1$. But this doesn't work.

Thus, there is only 1 solution $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: 0^4 != 1 + 1 isn't ? I am re-reading the text, and it ask for REAL number not integer... sorry...

Comment: Ty, will fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

$$y^4-x^4=x-y$$

If $x\ne y$

$$(y^2+x^2)(y+x)=-1$$

Assuming that last line should be $z^4=x+y$ we have

$$(x^2+y^2)z^4=-1$$

which has no solution.  Therefore $x$ must equal $y$.  Similarly, we can get $y=z$.  So we have

$$x^4=2x$$

The only real solutions are $x,y,$ and $z$ all equal $0$ or the cube root of $2$.

Comment: &(x^2+y^2)z^4 = -1& so z^4 = -1/(2*x^2)... What I am missing ?

Comment: @Siscia: If $x,y,z$ are real don't you think both $z^4$ and $x^2+y^2$ are positive?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Of course -.-, my bad... Still don't get how we arrive to x^4 = 2x

Comment: Ok I got it... Very stupid...

Answer (score 0):

1 ~ [y + z] mod(5) and 
1 ~ [z + x] mod(5) and
1 ~ [y + y] mod(5) from fermat's little theorem. Then since 5 is prime we know that each inverse must be unique. Thus this suggests that y mod(5) = z mod(5) = x mod(5) =  3 mod(5) 
As for finding all specific solutions I'm not sure.

Edit: I now see that you changed it to [y + x] so x,y,z it shouldn't be equivalent to 3 mod(5) as I said above, but then x, y are inverses mod (5) and so are y,z and z,x